# Implementing Bellman-Ford algorithm on finite state machine

Tags: state-machines

I wanted to ask whether it is even possible to implement the Bellman-Ford algorithm on a finite state machine.

How can you determine whether a machine will have a finite number of states or not?

Edit:
The Bellman-Ford algorithm finds the shortest path between 2 nodes in a set of nodes.

Comment: Is this not graph-searching?

Comment: It is graph searching, are those algorithms difficult to implement on FSM?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460501/a-algorithm-finite-state-machine

Comment: I read something here about A* algorithm on FSM, its very similar to bellman ford. I couldnt understand what the commenter wrote about Open and closed sets not bounded in size by a constant

Comment: I can imagine a push-down stack is required, which gives a strictly ordered access to the nodes. But even more flexible (random?) access, to nodes and an accumulated-distance of each trail-path, may be needed. There is a hierarchy of "compute machines", and those with just a stack-memory are LOW in the hierarchy.I think Fano wrote a book on compute-machines, under some title.

Comment: A* requires the sorting of the (incomplete) trial-paths, based on some cost; A* also requires ranking of the lowest trial-paths, based on a conservative trial-cost prediction engine. Since a bubble-sort in a round-robin queue suffices, you now have a complexity estimate for the state-machine: a circular queue, with access to two adjacent elements (trial-paths) and ability to swap the two elements (which does the sorting). Another tool is insertion-sort. I'd suggest reading Donald Knuth's books on this.

Comment: Very infomative,thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question?

Answer (score 2):

Snarky half-answer: Of course you can implement this in a FSM. Imagine an ordinary x86_64 processor sitting in a desktop computer. If I call each of the 2^32 bytes in memory part of my "state", wouldn't you agree that my desktop computer is a FSM?

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) on this algorithm gives a Python implementation, which can run on my computer, so yes. My FSM can implement the Bellman-Ford algorithm.

Now that we've proven it's possible to do with a non-infinite number of states, I'm sure it's possible to do with fewer states.

Comment: Im talking about direct hardware implementation of a FSM, not software implementation of a FSM

Comment: Essentially what youre saying is it depend on how much memory you have

Comment: @HappyDayYeah Theoretically, any algorithm that can be implemented in a "software" state machine can also be implemented in hardware. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: How would you represent the states for a machine which implements bellmand ford?